# I installed Pandas for python and i cant seem to get the dataframe references correct

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So the code below is creating three data frames based on a year. Each data frame is essentially the same except each year will have different stats for how players did. However, the header at the top of the datat frame gets repeated within every 20 rows or so. Im trying to figure how to get rid of it. So i figured that if i search the "Player" column for every instance "Player" is repeated within the column, that i could find the occurences and delete the row that it occurs in. At the end of my code, i ran a print function to see how many times the header row occurs within the data and it comes out to be 20 times. I just cant figure out the way to delete those rows.

```
import pandas as pd

year = ["2018", "2019", "2020"]
str = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{}/fantasy.htm"
url = str.format(year)

urlList = []
for season in year:
    url = str.format(season)
    urlList.append(url)

df2018 = pd.read_html(urlList[0], header=1)
df2019 = pd.read_html(urlList[1], header=1)
df2020 = pd.read_html(urlList[2], header=1)

print(df2020)


print(sum(df2020[0]["Player"] == "Player"))
```

P.S. I thought there was a way to reference a data frame variable by using the form of: dataframe.variable ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

year = ["2018", "2019", "2020"]
str = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{}/fantasy.htm"
url = str.format(year)

urlList = []
for season in year:
    url = str.format(season)
    urlList.append(url)

df2018 = pd.read_html(urlList[0], header=1)
df2019 = pd.read_html(urlList[1], header=1)
df2020 = pd.read_html(urlList[2], header=1)

df2020 = df2020[0]
df2020 = df2020[df2020['Rk'] != 'Rk']

print(df2020.head(50))
```

It filters the `Rk` column for the value "Rk", and excludes it when creating the new dataframe. I only ran the code for 2020, but you can repeat it for the other dataframes.

As a note, `pd.read_html()` makes a list of dataframes, rather than a dataframe, because an HTML website or file can contain multiple dataframes. That's why I included this line of code: 
`df2020 = df2020[0]`. It selects the first dataframe from the list.

If you need to reset the index, add this code to the end:

```
df2020 = df2020.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to help out pretty good! Im just wondering if i should use something else instead of the `pd.read_html()` if i know for a fact that there is only one dataframe?

Comment: No, `read_html()` is fine, it's just an extra step you have to take. There is no other alternative that I am aware of. If my answer worked, please mark it as the accepted answer, by clicking the checkmark on the left of my answer.

Comment: In Python, it's not a good idea to compare `== False`. And since `is False` won't work, you could bitwise-not (`~`) it with: `df[~df.Rk.str.contains('Rk')]`. Or just `df[df['Rk'] != 'Rk']`.

Comment: @aneroid Noted. I will update my answer. I didn't know that using `== False` is wrong in this context, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DapperDuck It's not an error, but `0 == False` ...and the option `is False` is worse. It's in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). `is` is reserved for identity checking - ensuring that two things are the _same_ thing, not just that they are equal - commonly for `is None` or `is not None`.